# How to simplify this 2 MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql

This must be an easy one, but I can't remember how I did it before.
I'm trying to make another query within the query where record IDs are match:

```
/*
    tables:
      models:
        model_id
        model_name

      models_years:
        model_year_id
        model_id
        year
*/

$models = DBW::run('SELECT * FROM models', [], true);
$models_years = DBW::run('SELECT * FROM models_years', [], true);

$output = [];

foreach ($models as $model)
{
    $years = [];
    foreach ($models_years as $model_year)
    {
        if ($model_year['model_id'] == $model['model_id'])
        {
            $years[] = $model_year['year'];
        }
    }
    $output[] = [
        'model_name' => $model['model_name'],
        'years' => $years
    ];
}

var_dump( $output );
```

I use PDO (settings: ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE = FETCH_ASSOC), and "DBW::run" function returns $stmt->fetchAll().
this is just an example of what I'm trying to do or improve, I know it's possible to do all of that in a single SQL, I've done it before and can't remember! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.model_name, y.`year`
FROM models AS m
LEFT JOIN models_years As y ON m.model_id = y.model_id
```

OR from your original question, the following might be what you need:

```
SELECT m.model_name, group_concat(y.`year`) AS `year`
FROM models AS m
LEFT JOIN models_years As y ON m.model_id = y.model_id
GROUP BY 1
```

Why?

1 - Join table to reduce SQL calls

2 - GROUP the result (BY 1 == BY m.model_name, just a lazy shorthand here)

3 - group_concat(...) will by default produce: year1,year2,year3,... and then you can use PHP explode(',', ...) to change to array if you need

Comment: Thank you! the second one is exactly what I wanted, and if you would please explain what happens there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, and use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the years for each model. Then use `explode()` to split that into an array.

```
$output = DBW::run('select m.model_name, GROUP_CONCAT(y.year) AS years
                    FROM models AS m
                    LEFT JOIN models_years AS y ON m.model_id = y.model_id
                    GROUP BY m.model_id', [], true);
foreach ($output as &$row) {
    $row['years'] = explode(',', $row['years']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort. It only lets me choose one as best, but this is also a working answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT model_name, year FROM models, models_years WHERE 
    models.model_id=models_years.model_id
```

Or, if you prefer the JOIN syntax,

```
SELECT model_name, year FROM models JOIN models_years ON 
    models.model_id=models_years.model_id
```

Answer (score -1):

another way to do this is with the sub select.

```
select * from models where model_id in (select model_id from models_years)
```

Comment: This is backwards. The original query will include all models, this will leave out any models that aren't in `model_years`.

Comment: You're also not returning the list of years. How will you fill in the `$years` array?